# How to convert any SDL_Surface to RGBA8888 format and back?

Tags: c, sdl

I want to convert any SDL_Surface my function receives to an RGBA8888 format surface, do *stuff*, and convert it back to its original format before return.

I'm working in C, by the way.

```
//------------------------------------------------
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
//------------------------------------------------
SDL_Surface* formattedSurf = SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat(surf, 
                                                      SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, 
                                                      0);
```

yields: "Problem description: Symbol 'SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888' could not be resolved" from Eclipse CDT and similar rsponses from gcc.

```
[Thu 13/09/26 14:40 PDT][pts/3][x86_64/linux-gnu/3.11.1-1-ARCH][5.0.2]
<justin@justin-14z:/tmp>
zsh/2 1821 % pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl
-D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL -lSDL -lpthread
```

Comment: What is `RGBA8888` format?

Comment: He means 32bits RGBA with 8 bits per channel

Comment: Please see @Zamallad's suggestion. That is exactly what I would like to do. Just cannot get the includes right, apparently.

Comment: Are you using SDL 1.2 or SDL 2? (not even sure it makes a difference, but interesting to know)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the surface you have is called `surface` and is valid i.e. not NULL

```
// Store the current pixel format flag
Uint32 currFormat = surface->format->format;

// Convert the surface to a new one with RGBA8888 format
SDL_Surface* formattedSurf = SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat(surf, 
                                                      SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, 
                                                      0);

if (formattedSurf != NULL) {

    // Free original surface
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);

    ////////////////////////
    // DO YOUR STUFF HERE //
    ////////////////////////

    // Re-create original surface with original format
    surface = SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat(formattedSurf, currFormat, NULL);

    // Free the formatted surface
    SDL_FreeSurface(formattedSurf);

}
else {

    /////////////////////////////////////
    // LOG A WARNING OR SOMETHING HERE //
    /////////////////////////////////////

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps I'm having an #include issue then, since I cannot get anything -- Eclipse CDT, scons, gcc -- to recognize `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888`. You suggestion was pretty much exactly what I tried initially. What includes are necessary for that snippet?

Comment: Hi just made a correction (changed the last param from NULL to 0 in the convert surface function for compatibility reasons). Including SDL.h should be enough for this to work. Maybe you could post the full code on pastebin?

Comment: It could also be a linker issue. Have you managed to get anything running in SDL - just a plain window or maybe drawing a bitmap (plenty of tutorials on the web).

Comment: It is an experiment I'm doing with the Wesnoth codebase. Unfortunately, I got frustrated and `git reset --hard` so I've got nothing to show you. See above for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I never had to use it, but it looks like `SDL_ConvertSurface` ([link](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlconvertsurface.html)) would do what you need if you create a `SDL_PixelFormat` ([link](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlpixelformat.html)) that corresponds to your `RGBA8888` format.

Comment: See above for more specifics on my problem that were added after you commented. Thanks.